# Lim of a function - excercise

Tags: calculus

Hi i try to do a question on limits and i want to ask if the way i calculated the answer was right. Here is the question and then my answer.
thank you!

*Question*:

for $n \in \Bbb N$, let $f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}$

in $[0,\infty)$

for  constant $x \in[0,\infty)$ calc: $\;\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$

$\\ \\ ---------------------$

*Answer*:

$$\frac{1}{f(x)} = \frac{1+n^2x^2}{nx} = \frac{1}{nx} + \frac{n^2x^2}{nx} = \frac{1}{nx} + nx $$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{f_n(x)} = \frac{1}{\infty} + \infty = 0 + \infty = \infty$

So $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x) = \frac{1}{\infty} = 0$.

What do you think about the calculation? 
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That computation is correct if $x>0$, but it makes no sense if $x=0$. Of course, that is not a problem, since$$(\forall n\in\mathbb N):f_n(0)=0.$$

Comment: Thank you very much!